# Custom module is not getting installed

Tags: odoo, openerp-8

I am using openERP 8 (odoo) and I have odoo installed here

```
/opt/odoo
```

Then the module for erp is installed here

```
/opt/odoo/addons/opencart_erp_connector
/opt/odoo/addons/opencart_openerp_stock
```

When I go to update the list from 
Update Module List

I get this

```
Odoo
Odoo Server Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 517, in _handle_exception
    return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 538, in dispatch
    result = self._call_function(**self.params)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 294, in _call_function
    return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/service/model.py", line 113, in wrapper
    return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 291, in checked_call
    return self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 754, in __call__
    return self.method(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 387, in response_wrap
    response = f(*args, **kw)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 953, in call_button
    action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 941, in _call_kw
    return getattr(request.registry.get(model), method)(request.cr, request.uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 237, in wrapper
    return old_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 391, in old_api
    result = new_api(recs, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 395, in new_api
    result = [method(rec, *args, **kwargs) for rec in self]
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/wizard/base_module_update.py", line 15, in update_module
    self.updated, self.added = self.env['ir.module.module'].update_list()
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 235, in wrapper
    return new_api(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/api.py", line 464, in new_api
    result = method(self._model, cr, uid, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base/module/module.py", line 654, in update_list
    handler.load_addons()
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/http.py", line 1254, in load_addons
    m = __import__('openerp.addons.' + module)
  File "/opt/odoo/openerp/modules/module.py", line 77, in load_module
    mod = imp.load_module('openerp.addons.' + module_part, f, path, descr)
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/opencart_erp_connector/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    import core_updated_files
  File "/opt/odoo/addons/opencart_erp_connector/core_updated_files.py", line 23, in <module>
    import pooler
ImportError: No module named pooler
```

Will appreciate any help
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Okay, Please do a small change in `account_test.py`, add import file from `from openerp import pooler`. Save and restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this .py file

```
/opt/odoo/addons/opencart_erp_connector/core_updated_files.py
```

Now go to above path (line no 23) and change the import statement

```
import pooler
```

to

```
from openerp import pooler
```

Restart server and refresh the browser.

Hope this will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

What is the filestructure of your custom module?
Can you provide us the filenames and some code?

it should be something like:

```
__init__.py
__pooler__.py
pooler.py
```

The **__init__.py** should contain:

```
import pooler
```